# What's the simplest way to run an OSX openFrameworks project on a Raspberry pi?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspbian, openframeworks

I've built a relatively simple oF app which uses several 3rd-party addons. I've created the project with the project generator, and coded the whole thing in Xcode on OSX.

Now, I need to use this app on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. I've successfully compiled the armv6 version of oF, but I now need to compile the actual project.

**So far I thought of the following options:**

- Try to get code::blocks running on the Pi, install oF for codeblocks, recreate the project and build.
- Try to set up Ubuntu as a virtual desktop on my mac, set up a cross-compiler [like this,](http://openframeworks.cc/setup/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-Cross-compiling-guide.html) recreate the project and build.
- Pretend to be a magician – set up the OSX project on the Pi so that I could maybe compile it with `make`, except I have no idea whether this is possible at all.
- ???

---

**So my question is:** Given a severe deficiency of time and general skill when it comes to linux/compiling C++, what is the easiest way for me to get my oF app running on the Pi?

Many thanks!

Comment: I would go for the second approach, but what about generalizing the Xcode project to a CMake project on the Mac first? That would give you a good starting point when you move over to Linux or some other platform.

Comment: the "magician" option doesn't sound good. A cross-compile *may* be a pain in the neck, so *if* you can OpenFrameworks compile on the Pi itself, I would suggest you try compiling there. Don't try to use CodeBlocks though – it's a huge and monstrous editor for which the tiny computer may not have enough resources. Just use `make` and `gcc`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I managed to compile everything with `make`, there were a lot of things Xcode seems to be doing automatically that had to be taken care of, but it does compile now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute easiest (and perhaps even fastest when accounting for the extra cross-compiler setup time) way is to use a Raspberry Pi 2 and compile everything directly on the board using all 4 cores.  It is actually quite quick and easy to set up.  To set it up, follow these instructions:

http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/raspberry-pi-2-setup-guide/

If you would like to use a more friendly IDE like Xcode, I would recommend developing your code on OSX and then copy the project folder over to the Pi2 and execute the makefiles as noted in the setup guide above.

Comment: thanks, I'm using a B+ so the compiling takes ages, but works well!